# operator for approximate equality testing in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I often need to check if `expr1==expr2`, where checking for symbolic equality is hard, but a numeric check suffices

To deal with such cases it would be neat to have `TildeTilde` work like `Equal` but instead of checking symbolic equality it would substitute unknowns with numeric values and check for numeric equality at several points.

Unknowns are things that "look like" variables in the expression. The ones I can think of have form `x`,`x[1,2]` and `Subscript[x,2,3]`. Any tips welcome!

**edit**

usually I do something like below, but it requires specifying variables, sometimes requires changing Chop tolerance, and "10 samples" seems arbitrary. An ideal tester would be a function that works like `Equals` and guarantees meaningful `False` answers. (to complement `Equals` which has meaningful `True` answers)

```
approxEqual[expr1_, expr2_, vars_] := 
  Chop[(expr1 - expr2 /. Thread[vars -> #]) & /@ 
     RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, Length[vars]}]] == Table[0, {10}];
expr1 = 1/Sqrt[2] Log[Cosh[q + x/Sqrt[2]] Sech[q - x/Sqrt[2]]];
expr2 = Sqrt[2] ArcTanh[Tanh[q] Tanh[x/Sqrt[2]]];
approxEqual[expr1, expr2, {q, x}]
```

As a side-note, apparently Maple uses [this](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=32465&dl=ACM&coll=DL) algorithm for such equality testing

Comment: numeric testing would be just as difficult, since floating point numbers is not real numbers.

Comment: they are, if you squint hard enough

Comment: I see two key problems: how do you decide what is a variable (x[1,2] looks like a function call to me), and how do you decide on the domain of those variables?

Comment: if evaluation of expr1 contains x[1,2], it's an unknown that can be replaced with a numeric quantity. As far as domain, this could be another option with a default, for me, Real would cover almost all the cases

Comment: @Yaro Squinting lenses: http://www.hplusmagazine.com/articles/toys-tools/micro-machines-and-opto-electronics-contact-lense

Comment: There's `PossibleZeroQ` - but in the example you give, `PossibleZeroQ[expr1 - expr2, Assumptions -> {x > 0, q > 0}]` returns `False` even though `FullSimplify[expr1 - expr2 == 0, x > 0 && q > 0]` returns `True`...

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why FullSimplify works with that restriction, you can see from plot that equality holds negative values `Plot3D[Chop[expr1 - expr2], {x, -2, 2}, {q, -2, 2}]`

Comment: Actually, `FullSimplify[expr1-expr2==0,{x,q}\\[Element]Reals]` also returns `True`. I just thought the positive condition might be easier for `PossibleZeroQ`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is somewhat straightforward if you use [`FindMaximum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindMaximum.html) as a jumping-off point:

```
In[64]:= FindMaximum[expr1 - expr2, q, x]

During evaluation of In[64]:= FindMaximum::fmgz: Encountered a gradient that
is effectively zero. The result returned may not be a maximum; it may be a 
minimum or a saddle point. >>

Out[64]= {1.11022*10^-16, {q -> 1., x -> 1.}}
```

Thus:

```
approxEqual[lhs_, rhs_, tol_: 10^-10] :=
 Module[{vars},
  vars = DeleteDuplicates[
    Cases[{lhs,rhs}, s_Symbol /; Not[ValueQ[s]], Infinity]
  ];
  Chop[
    First[
     Quiet[FindMaximum[Abs[lhs - rhs], Evaluate[Sequence @@ vars]]]
    ], 
    tol] == 0
  ]

In[65]:= approxEqual[expr1, expr2]
Out[65]= True

In[66]:= approxEqual[expr1, expr2, 10^-20]
Out[66]= False
```

Obviously, in general this is subject to various numerical error issues that you can address with `AccuracyGoal` / `PrecisionGoal` / `WorkingPrecision` / etc. options to `FindMaximum`. You could also repeat `FindMaximum` for multiple starting points for the variables.

As an aside, note that `TildeTilde`, (i.e. `~~`), is the infix operator for [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringExpression.html).

HTH!

Comment: Wow, neat idea, probably more robust than randomly sampling points. BTW, TildeTilde is an "Operator without built-in meaning" in Mathematica 7

Comment: I stand corrected! I ought to know these things. ;-) I always read `~~` as "tilde-tilde" in my head.

Comment: Should perhaps take absolute value -- `Abs[expr1-expr2]`?

Comment: Speechlesssss .. "somewhat straightforward" ha!

Comment: The "maximum" value of `(-x^2) - (-1.00001 x)^2` is 0, but the difference between the two functions as x goes to +/- infinity is increasingly large, but negative. I think `Abs` is necessary.

Comment: If you use `Norm[expr1-expr2]` it work for vectors and matrices as well.

Comment: +1 for  `Cases[expr,s_Symbol/;Not@ValueQ[s],Infintiy]`  -- I was sure it was going to fail on `Sin[x]`, but depth-first comes to the rescue. Very nice!

Comment: Thanks, I googled this 7 years later, and came across my own question, accepting the answer since it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

I really think it is worthwhile specifying patterns and ranges for the symbols you want to replace. The following code is a polished version of an equality test generator I have used for a while.
My take on this is to have `numEqual=MakeEqualityTest[...]` generate an equality test that you can then apply with e.g. `lhs ~numEqual~rhs` or whatever you prefer. Your question was a welcome chance to polish up some code I had around, and in the end it got too big to fit here, so i put it out at [github](https://github.com/Japanuspus/EqualityTester/blob/master/EqualityTester.m) (link is directly to browseable code).

Key features:

- Use Michael's depth first `Cases` trick for a reasonable auto-pattern
- Using `Norm[#1-#2]&` as a distance test to handle vectors, matrices, etc.
- The number of sampling points depends on the number of independent variables.
- A flexible system for specifying distributions (e.g. you can replace the symbols with complex numbers or matrices).

Example use:

```
numeq=MakeEqualityTester[];
(Cos[x]^2+Sin[x]^2)~numeq~1
Sqrt[x^2]~numeq~x

Out[5]= True
During evaluation of In[4]:= EqualityTest::notEqual: The expressions Sqrt[x^2] and x were not equal at the following point:
Out[6]= {x->-0.352399}
```

You can also call directly, via a utility function:

```
EqualityTest[1,Cos[x]^2+Sin[x]^2]
Out[7]= True
```

And here is an example of special symbols and distributions:

```
poseq=MakeEqualityTester[{
    Subscript[y,_]:>RandomReal[{10,11}],
    Automatic 
  },Tolerance-> 10^(-5)];
x ~poseq~ Sqrt[x^2]
Subscript[y,1] ~poseq~ Sqrt[Subscript[y,1]^2]

During evaluation of In[18]:= EqualityTest::notEqual: The expressions x and Sqrt[x^2] were not equal at the following point:
Out[19]= {x->-0.272029}
Out[20]= True
```